# how to create a dictionary from a merged django queryset

Tags: django, django-views

Django newbie here trying create a dictionary looking like this `{<Course: Phonics>: [40,72,76], <Course: Social Studies>: [48,72,60]}`(each value in the list is the subject-score per term) from a merged queryset `bla = result1 | result2 | result3` where

`result1 =  Result.objects.filter(pupil__exact = pk,session = session1)`

`result2 =  Result.objects.filter(pupil__exact = pk,session = session2)`

`result3 =  Result.objects.filter(pupil__exact = pk,session = session3)`

Here is snippet Result & Session class in models.py

```
class Result(models.Model):
    pupil = models.ForeignKey('Student', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    subject_course = models.ForeignKey('Course', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    subject_score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    session = models.ForeignKey('Session', on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):  
        return '{}, {} result'.format(self.pupil.surname,self.session)


class Session(models.Model):
    sessionedu = models.CharField(choices = SESSION ,max_length=20)
    term = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=TERM)
    resumption = models.DateField(blank=True,default= one_month_away)
    #active = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    class Meta:

        verbose_name = "Session"
        verbose_name_plural = "Sessions"

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.sessionedu, self.term)
```

thanks
[image: Result Class]

`<QuerySet [<Result: Ali, 2020/2021 1st Term result>, <Result: Ali, 2020/2021 2nd Term result>, <Result: Ali, 2020/2021 3rd Term result>, <Result: Ali, 2020/2021 1st Term result>, <Result: Ali, 2020/2021 2nd Term result>, <Result: Ali, 2020/2021 3rd Term result>]>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can post-process the `Result`s with [**`groupby`** [python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import attrgetter

qs = Result.objects.filter(
    pupil=pk,
    session__in=[session1, session2, session3]
).select_related('subject_course').order_by('subject_course', 'session')

result = {
    k: [v.subject_score for v in vs]
    for k, vs in groupby(qs, attrgetter('subject_course'))
}
```

Comment: Interesting way to go about it, but the list in the dictionary is the same for all the subject_course

Comment: @kufopo: exactly how does the data looks, can you share the (sample) data from the database. [[edit]](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65718450/edit) the question.

Comment: @Kufopo: you shared everything, except the subject scores which are the interesting part here :).

Comment: @ Willem Van Onsem, i have added an image and the **qs** output. Your solution produces: ``` {<Course: Social Studies>: [48, 90, 39, 50, 70, 25], <Course: Phonics>: [48, 90, 39, 50, 70, 25]}```, instead of ``` {<Course: Social Studies>: [48, 90, 39, ], <Course: Phonics>: [ 50, 70, 25]}```

Comment: @kufopo: I made a typo, it is `for k, vs in ...`, but it is odd that there is a `vs` in the first place.

Comment: @ Willem Van Onsem you mean **qs**

Comment: @kufopo: no.... `vs` is the second item in the groups that `groupby` will emit.